# How to fix node-abac module "Cannot set property '_validator' of undefined"

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use the `node-abac` module for Access Control. I realize it hasn't been updated in 4 years (at time of writing), but maybe this is fixable.

After setting up `node-abac` with a policy, I receive the titular error at runtime here:

`node_modules\node-abac\lib\abac.js:27 this._validator = new Validator(Policy);`

Policy:

```js
const nodeAbac = require('node-abac');

const accessPolicy = {
    attributes: {
        user: {
            role: 'Is A Site Owner',
            dateJoined: 'Member for over 1 year'
        }
    },
    rules: {
        'fullAccess': {
            attributes: {
                'user.role': {
                    comparison_type: 'String',
                    comparison: 'isStrictlyEqual',
                    value: 'owner'
                }
            }
        },
        'canModerateReviews': {
            attributes: {
                'user.dateJoined': {
                    comparison_type: "datetime",
                    comparison: "isLessRecentThan",
                    value: "-1Y"
                },
                'user.reviews.length': {
                    comparison_type: 'numeric',
                    comparison: 'isGreaterThanEqualTo',
                    value: '12'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

const accessControl = nodeAbac(accessPolicy);

module.exports = accessControl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I was constructing `accessControl` incorrectly, without the `new` keyword.

```
const accessControl = new nodeAbac(accesspolicy);
```

Now on to find other implementation errors!